# Brownian motion square

Tags: brownian-motion

I need to calculate for Brownian motion $dBt^2$ and $dBt^4$. For $dBt^2$, I think that it is correct to use Ito's lemma.

So we get:
$$ dBt^2=(1/2)\cdot 2 \cdot dt +2\cdot Bt\cdot dBt$$

Is this correct?

What about $dBt^4$?

Comment: Your formula is correct. What about using Ito's lemma with the function $f(x) = x^4$?

Comment: So it is $ dBt^4 = 4B_t^3 dBt+1/2 \cdot 12 \cdot t^2 dt ? $

Comment: Almost! It should be $dB_t^4 = 4B_t^3dB_t + \frac12\cdot12\cdot B_t^2dt$. You have to evaluate the second derivative in $B_t$.

Comment: @Rik93 I need to calculate $dSt^4$, where St is geometric Brownian motion. How about that?

Comment: Have you also seen Ito's lemma for general processes? And what definition do you use for geometric Brownian motion?